# Resolving local Javascript dependencies Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC on my projects and my javascript/css references are in a _Layout.cshtml.

I'm planning to use different _Latouts on my project and my problem is that I'll just copy paste these references to other layouts that I'll be using.

For Example:

I have resources:

**_javascript1** depends on **_javascript2**

**_javascript3** depends on **_javascript2**

I'm looking for a way to automatically resolve dependencies (primarily in javascript) so that I will not have a mistake to have duplicate reference on **_javascript2**

Comment: Have you considered to use Webpack, RequireJS or something similar?

Comment: I'll look into it... The problem is that I have no idea about these tools... I tried to search for it in google using my keywords but giving me results that is not related to my problem. Probably poor keyword choices. Thanks man!

Comment: If you could post some more information regarding the issue that you are facing, with some more code, it will be really helpful, so please update the question, in order to provide better help. What are the different layouts? How you intend to use JavaScript code there? What is the actual problem in code?